# Combining 2 State Machines?

Tags: serial, programming

I want to gain from recent advice from this forum by re-doing my project using 'state machine' logic if possible, in an effort to reduce wasted processor time and variables usage.

I'm starting from Nick Gammons '*state machine to process input from the serial port*' example http://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine, which shows all the different possible combinations for all the special control character 'events' against all the possible machine states - essentially a 2-dimensional grid.

I've refined my goal to the processing of serial input in a format of "**command  [parameters]  [options]**", similar to a DOS command-line format, eg:  **DIR  "c:\program files"  /w /s**. This would free me from needing large Buffer[] and Header[] string, and avoides any parsing,

Therefore my event control characters are space, comma, single-quote, double-quote, forward-slash, Carraige Return, and my 'states' are **NULL, COMMAND, PARAMETER, OPTIONS**

The OPTIONS state adds characters to a temporary option[] string until a comma or space delimiter or Carraige Return causes that option to be processed as appropriate, perhaps saving its value to a recognised variable.

The COMMAND and PARAMETER 'states' add characters to their corresponding command[] and parameters[] strings, including the special control characters if they are contained within either single or double quotes (thereby allowing quotes as part of a string if used within a pair of the other type).

So there appears to be a second state machine needed for **NoQuotes, SingleQuotes and DoubleQuotes** to modify the operation of the COMMAND, PARAMETER and OPTIONS states.

This is where I run out of neurons, because all I see is an impossibly complex 2-machine-state 3-dimensional grid with too many possible permutations.

But I suspect there must be a very practical way to implement this, because it lies at the heart of almost all command-line utilities dating back to a time when processor power and memory availability were scarcer than hens teeth, and those old DOS command-line utilities needed to be as mimimal as was possible, including their command-line parsing.

So can anybody suggest a feasible model (machine-state or otherwise) for getting command-line type format from input?

UPDATE

Oh dear... I've just seen another complication I hadn't spotted before, which is that '/' options are not necessarily always at the end, which means that except if the options state changes by carraige-return, options state change by delimiter have to return to the state prior to the options state change (phew, I hope that makes some sense).  Anyway, I think it's back to drawing board because this approach seems likely to be too complicated, as the 2 answers already suggest.

Comment: The common way of handing interacting states is to expand the interactions into their own state.  i.e. PARAMETER vs SingleQuotes_PARAMETER DoubleQuotes_PARAMETER, where their processing could share much the same code.    See https://github.com/Traumflug/Teacup_Firmware/blob/master/gcode_parse.c for an big example.   Also, this is too broad (you don't have a syntax for us to use) and is really off topic for an Arduino-focused forum.

Comment: Another way to think of it as a state  machine is that your state space is a many-dimensional vector of state variables, with a {COMMAND, PARAMETER[],OPTIONS[],etc...)

Comment: The question is very much Arduino because I wish to read incoming serial and 'sort' it into command plus optional parameter plus optional control-options, therefore mention of DOS command-line was merely giving a syntax example of the required serial format.

Comment: Some sort of general DOS syntax, or the much more limited syntax for a particular command?  With a particular command, there are only a limited number of parameters and options, and your /parser/ state machine can sort them out into their /process/ state variables somewhat like Teacup does.

Comment: It's for whatever local 'commands' and 'parameters the arduino is programmed tolook for in  incoming serial, eg: 'LED1 ON', or 'IRSEND "NEC 0xFFEE9123 32".    
The options are for optional arduino-to-arduino sending of control info, such as /c(hecksum)=nnn,  /l(ength)=nnn, /s(ource)=nnn etc.     The idea is to read incoming serial a byte at a time and send to command or params or options on the fly, rather than needing to parse an additional large buffer string after.

Comment: I would think you can't dispatch the command until the last character of the last option is parsed--so the COMMAND, PARAMETERS, and OPTIONS must all be merely a vector of parameters for the next stage of processing.  You need to collect them all before moving on.  Is the 'LED1' in 'LED1 ON' a command?  ///  For your updated Q, the '\n' changes the state of the system from parsing bytes into the cleaning up the parameter state and executing a command state/oneshot, for example https://github.com/Traumflug/Teacup_Firmware/blob/master/gcode_parse.c#L362 to #390.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't think Nick advised to do command line pattern parsing with a state machine. His example is about changing a state machine based on command line input.
I have written some command line parsers and I never used a state machine to do so. I would not advice to use a state machine to do so.
Simple string parsing is far easier.

**Edit To answer the remark below:**
I would not advice to go byte by byte. I'd advice to go the line by line way.
I have written a library to do read line by line and an article on how that one works. http://blog.baeyens.it/#post16
Here a link to the lib https://github.com/jantje/libraries/tree/master/SerialCommunicator.
Here is a parcing code example. It is not so interesting for you as I have it done in a stage by stage way in a very high level way of coding.
https://github.com/jantje/libraries/blob/master/SerialBridgeCommunicator/SerialBridgeCommunicator.cpp#L21

Basically the algorithm is=
1 Take the first word;
2 identify the word.
3 If the command is complete ->do it
 else Send the rest of the string to a specialized piece of code. (which has the same algorithm)

Comment: I thought my needs were the same as Nicks example - to read incoming serial a byte at a time and send to command or params or options on the fly then action them as appropriate after reading a carraige-return, rather than then needing to parse an additional large buffer string after.  But no point me shooting for the moon - you mentioned doing command line parser previously... would you happen to have a suitable flowchart or algorithm?

Comment: I would not advice to go byte by byte. I'd advice to go the line by line way.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: - don't try to "moosh" (that's a technical-term!) the state-machine heirarchy down into one large, flat state-machine. That way lies madness. Keep your { NULL, COMMAND, PARAMETER, OPTIONS } state machine, for instance, and, wherever you need something more than simple string collection in one of those states, call a parser SM appropriate to the kind(s) of input you expect at that point - a number, a quoted string, an option specifier, etc.

Comment: I think I understand (probably too late to avoid madness though cos I think the state machine may have already 'mooshed' my head).  As you say, use NULL, COMMAND, PARAMETER as the states to change through. And even though NoQuotes, SingleQuotes, Double-Quotes and possibly Options might justify a state machine themselves, best just to treat them as separate processes within the main state machine.

Comment: You might also consider as a mid-point, a universal parser that can handle various input types, but separate from the main SM. You'll know best, once you quick sketch up a couple of SM hierarchies (that's 'sketch' as in 'circles and arrows', not as in 'coding').